# What is the current most accurate measurement of the cosmological transition redshift

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, redshift

Does anyone know what the current most accurate measurement of the redshift for when the Universe's expansion changed from decelerating to accelerating (with a reference)?

Comment: Accuracy implies the comparison of at least 2 independent measurements. Maybe you mean the Hubble constant? The expansion of the Universe is occurring during this epoch - which makes us very special in the history of the Universe.

Comment: No, the OP means papers like this https://www.researchgate.net/publication/273472183_Transition_redshift_in_fT_cosmology_and_observational_constraints